# Matrix of Linear Transformation $T(X)=XA-AX$ for a given $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I was reading about commutator of two matrices $A,B$ which is defined as $[A,B]:=AB-BA$.

I am just curious to know if for a given matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, the matrix of the linear transformation $T:\mathbb R^{n\times n} \to \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ defined by $T(X)=[X,A]$ has any "nice" structure involving $A$ with respect to canonical bases?

The matrix of $T$ will be a $n^2\times n^2$ matrix and usual computations using canonical bases in $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is becoming complicated to me. So I am hoping if there is any way to sort it out if there is any "nice" structure of the matrix of $T$.

I am sorry, this might be simple or already asked. I will be grateful if someone helps me.

Comment: See [the Sylvester equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation). There's a nice formula for the matrix involving the Kronecker product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the canonical basis of $\Bbb R^n$ (the columns of the identity). Presumably, your canonical basis is
$$
\{e_1e_1^T,e_1e_2^T,\dots,e_1e_n^T,e_2e_1^T,e_2e_2^T,\dots,e_2e_n^T,\dots\}
$$
which is to say that we take $\{e_ie_j^T\}_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}$ in *lexicographical order*.  We can nicely identify this with the basis $\{e_i \otimes e_j\}_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}$ of $\Bbb R^n \otimes \Bbb R^n$, where $\otimes$ denotes the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_linear_maps).

For the map $X \mapsto XA$, we find
$$
T(e_ie_j^T) = e_ie_j^TA = e_i (A^Te_j)^T
$$
So, we can define the map by $x \otimes y \mapsto x \otimes (Ay)$.  We can conclude that the matrix associated with this map is $I \otimes A^T$.

Similarly, the matrix associated with $X \mapsto AX$ is $A \otimes I$.

All together, $X \mapsto XA - AX$ has matrix $I \otimes A^T - A \otimes I$.